# Cutting a galette and hitting the fève

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

We have in France a tradition of eating in January countless [*galettes des rois*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_cake#France)<sup>(*)</sup>. Hidden inside is a *fève*, a small figurine (it was originally a coin). The one who gets the *fève* without breaking a tooth is crowned queen or king.

To give some context, the home-made *galette* we ate today, together with its *fève*

[image] [image]

As I was cutting the *galette*, my son asked

> I wonder what the probability to hit the *fève* when making a cut is?

Now I wonder as well.

In the tradition of spherical cows in a vacuum, a *galette* with its *fève* can be simplified as

[image]

where $r_g$ and $r_f$ are the radii of, respectively, the *galette* and the *fève*. $d_f$ is the distance of the center of the *fève* from the center of the *galette*. EDIT: the placement of the *fève* is random.

Asking for a full calculation of the probability would be too much :), so my question is: **how should I approach this calculation**, especially since it will be dependent on $d_f$ (which will probably have a squared distribution). Any hints and warnings are welcome<sup>(**)</sup>.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> We are of course talking about the only proper one - the northern one (in case someone has doubts from Wikipedia). The proper drink for a *galette des rois* is [*cidre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cider), of course from Brittany

<sup>(**)</sup> The prize could be a part of the *galette* but it is already gone.

Comment: I guess you could inverse the problem by saying: I have a galette cut in 12 evenly sized slices (30° each). Now I throw a small ball with radius $r_f$ on that galette and I am wondering with which probability it hits a cut line. This is an alterantive problem to drawing evenly distanced lines with distance $d$ on a piece of paper and throwing a needle with length $d'<d$ on there, looking for the probability that it has an intersection with a line when it lands... see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem

Comment: It should be said that the term "rois" (kings) do not refer to the kings of France but to the three Magi.

Comment: To prevent a misunderstanding which I might have fallen vicitim to: Do you only want to cut once? Or do you want to cut several times to redistribute the galette?

Comment: A solution (in french): https://zestedesavoir.com/articles/3409/quelle-est-la-probabilite-de-couper-sur-la-feve/

Comment: @Jfischer: this si actually what I was thinking about right now. Initially I had the first cut in mind (a straight cut from the center to the edge), but then I started to wonder how that would work for a family & friends of *n* people (in other words, what's the probability to hit the *fève* when cutting parts for everyone). Since I am an ex-physicist, I also started to add a small gap to hide the *fève* in case it would be right at the edge of the cut. And then started to wonder how to simulate this instead of calculating :)

Comment: Given $d_f$, I think you can say that the probability of the cut hitting the fève is $\frac{1}{\pi} \sin^{-1}(r_g/d_f)$

Comment: @JeanMarie: thank you! everything has already been asked (and answered) I see :)

Comment: The idea of objects in a cake is central to Smith of Wootton Major by J.R.R. Tolkien, author of the Lord of the Rings.... https://tolkienlibrary.com/booksbytolkien/smithofwoottonm/description.htm  I imagine it has been translated into French.

Comment: *the only proper one - the northern one*: you keep the responsibility of this claim, and also the mathematical burden! The meridional *couronne* is easier (and may I assert that people with such regional claims are you are more likely to get the *fève* than the *sujet* in those, but that's probably difficult to prove!)

Comment: @Joce: I hope the fact that I was joking was clear (especially for a lover of regionalisms as myself) :) I hope I will not end up like in that [dramatic case](https://www.legorafi.fr/2013/03/20/toulouse-il-se-fait-abattre-de-46-balles-dans-le-corps-pour-avoir-demande-un-pain-au-chocolat/). For our non-French friends, the Gorafi is the equivalent of The Onion.

Comment: Oh gosh, I sure hope so too! Yes, I could get that you were joking, and was joking too—what even the French Wikipedia doesn't say is that in the South, if it's the *fève* you get, rather than the other token (called *sujet*), you're the *couillon* (sucker!) but nothing worse than that ;)

Comment: @Joce: cool, it is just that sometimes what sounds funny in one's head  is not that obvious in writing, so I should have been more explicit :) Bonne année :)

Comment: [disappearing comment] Hi there, thanks so much for the [proposed edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1813151). I rejected it because elaborating on the computation actually distracts from my Answer's thesis: as explained in the post, the computation is merely tangential to my main message. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

J'adore la galette des rois.

[image: Galette des rois]

Using your diagram, and assuming a cut with the knife is a a full line segment from the center of the galette to the edge of the crust, the probability of hitting the feve is ratio of the green area including the red area) over the area of the full disk.

Since $\widehat {OBA}$ is a right triangle, you can compute the angle at $O$ as
$$\hat O = 2\arcsin \frac{BA}{OA} = 2\arcsin \frac{r_f}{d_f}$$
Thus the probability is $$\frac{\left(\arcsin \frac{r_f}{d_f}\right) r_g^2}{\pi r_g^2}=\frac{\arcsin \frac{r_f}{d_f}}{\pi}$$

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't you divide the area of the circular sector by $2$?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, sir.

Comment: Thank you. I did not make it clear in my question that the placement of the *fève* is random (I probably made it worse by explicitly mentioning $d_f$ and not highlighting enough its distribution. I will clarify the question.